# Understanding proof about a group and homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, group-homomorphism

I have a book about group theory and there was the following question:

> Let $G$ be a set of all the real matrices in the following form: $\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\
> -b & a
> \end{pmatrix}$ when $a^2+b^2>0$.
>
> 1. Prove that $G$ is a group.
> 2. Prove that $G\cong (C^\times,\cdot )$.

I successfully proved that $G$ is a group. Now I'm trying to prove the second sub-question. In the book they suggested to declare the following function:

$$ f:\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\
-b & a
\end{pmatrix} \to a+ib$$

Also they wrote "obviously $f$ is bijection", and then they proved the Homomorphism equation. The only part that I didn't understand is why $f$ is a bijection, and why it is so obvious? How can I prove it formally?

Comment: Which book are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbb{C}^\times=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and since each $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ can be written in one and only one way as $a+bi$ with $a$ and $b$ not both equal to $0$ ($\iff a^2+b^2>0$), it is clear that $f$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

To see that the map is a bijection note that the kernel consists precisely of the identity matrix and hence the map is injective. Indeed if $f(A)=1=a+ib$ for some matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a& b\\
-b& a
\end{bmatrix}
$,
then we have that $a=1$ and $b=0$. Conversely given any $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus {0}$, let $a=\text{Re}(z)$, and $b=\text{Im}(z)$, so that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a& b\\
-b& a
\end{bmatrix}\to z
$$
whence the map is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

For every complex number $\mathbb{C}-\{0\} \ni x:=a+bi$,(hence $a \neq 0$ or $b \neq 0$). Consider the matrix 
$$y=\begin{bmatrix}
    a       & b \\
    -b       & a \\
\end{bmatrix}$$, The determinant of this matrix of $a^2+b^2 >0$ and it gets map to $a+bi$ by $f$(that is it! $f(y)=x$). So this shows surjectivity!

For injectivity, we have if $0\neq a+bi=f(A)=f(B)=c+di \neq 0$, then $a=c, b=d$. so 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    a       & b \\
    -b       & a \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    c       & d \\
    -d       & c \\
\end{bmatrix}=B$$
And so $f$ is bijective!

Comment: I understand why $f$ is injective, but I don't understand why $f$ is surjective. I know that I need to show that for every $y\in Y$ there is $x\in X$ so $f(x)=y$. From similar question I say that I need to point for that exact $x$ to prove the example. Which $x$ should I use?

Comment: I edited a bit my answer I don't know if that helps?